# Knex.js Schema: Multicolumn Index

Tags: node.js, knex.js

Is there a way to specify a multicolumn index in the Knex.js schema?  Or must one drop to raw and do an `alter table`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Figured this out.  You can use the .index chainable on the table directly and pass an array for the index fields and a name for the index.

```
knex.schema.createTable(function(table) {
  table.bigInteger('_id').unsigned().primary();
  table.string('fieldA');
  table.string('fieldB');
  table.index(['fieldA','fieldB'], 'index_name');
});
```

Comment: that documentation :(

Comment: seems that composite index's comment will lead a mysql error.